# "pipenv install" fails installing Django but "pip install" command works fine

Tags: pipenv-install

Unable install django using "pipenv install django" and "python -m pipenv install django". But "pip install django" works.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Sahama.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-yfFxrCji\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\project.py", line 545, in _parse_pipfile
return tomlkit.parse(contents)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Sahama.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-yfFxrCji\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\tomlkit\api.py", line 83, in parse
return Parser(string).parse()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Sahama.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-yfFxrCji\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\tomlkit\parser.py", line 158, in parse
key, value = self._parse_table()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Sahama.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-yfFxrCji\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\tomlkit\parser.py", line 998, in _parse_table
item = self._parse_item()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Sahama.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-yfFxrCji\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\tomlkit\parser.py", line 242, in _parse_item
return self._parse_key_value(True)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Sahama.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-yfFxrCji\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\tomlkit\parser.py", line 315, in _parse_key_value
key = self._parse_key()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Sahama.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-yfFxrCji\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\tomlkit\parser.py", line 364, in _parse_key
return self._parse_bare_key()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Sahama.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-yfFxrCji\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\tomlkit\parser.py", line 408, in _parse_bare_key
raise self.parse_error(EmptyKeyError)
pipenv.vendor.tomlkit.exceptions.EmptyKeyError: Empty key at line 5 col 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
File "", line 88, in *run_code
File "C:\Users\Sahama.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-yfFxrCji\Lib\site-packages\pipenv_*main**.py", line 4, in 
cli()
File "C:\Users\Sahama.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-yfFxrCji\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1130, in **call**
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Sahama.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-yfFxrCji\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli\options.py", line 58, in main
return super().main(*args, **kwargs, windows_expand_args=False)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Sahama.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-yfFxrCji\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1055, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Sahama.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-yfFxrCji\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1657, in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Sahama.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-yfFxrCji\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1404, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Sahama.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-yfFxrCji\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 760, in invoke
return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Sahama.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-yfFxrCji\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Sahama.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-yfFxrCji\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 760, in invoke
return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Sahama.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-yfFxrCji\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 233, in install
do_install(
File "C:\Users\Sahama.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-yfFxrCji\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\routines\install.py", line 79, in do_install
pre = project.settings.get("allow_prereleases")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Sahama.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-yfFxrCji\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\project.py", line 575, in settings
return self.parsed_pipfile.get("pipenv", {})
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Sahama.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-yfFxrCji\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\project.py", line 523, in parsed_pipfile
parsed = self._parse_pipfile(contents)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Sahama.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-yfFxrCji\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\project.py", line 549, in _parse_pipfile
return toml.loads(contents)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Sahama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tomllib_parser.py", line 116, in loads
raise suffixed_err(src, pos, "Invalid statement")
tomllib.TOMLDecodeError: Invalid statement (at line 5, column 1)

I've tried to install Django using the following commands. But none of this work.

pipenv install django
python -m pipenv install django